# Providing multiple models for a template class to choose from

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

I am currently playing with templates to build a color class. I am using templates because a color can be defined and stored using different [color spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_color_spaces_and_their_uses) or [color models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model).

So basically, I came up with a class that takes a color model class as template parameter and inherits from it, in order to access model-specific methods as `red()`, `green()` and `blue()` for the RGB model, or `hue()`, `saturation()` and `value()` for the HSV model. I also wrote some model classes as well as some convenience typedefs for colors and model-converter functions.

```
template <typename T>
class Color : public T {
public:
    typedef T Model;

    using T::T;

    // This is meant to convert colors with different models
    template <typename U>
    explicit Color(const Color<U>& c);
};

class RGB {
public:
    static constexpr auto name = "RGB";

    RGB() = default;
    RGB(unsigned int argb);
    RGB(unsigned int r, unsigned int g, unsigned int b, unsigned int a = 0xFF);

    RGB lighter(double factor = 1.2) const;
    RGB negative() const;
    RGB greyscale() const;

    unsigned int argb() const;
    unsigned int red() const;
    unsigned int green() const;
    unsigned int blue() const;
    unsigned int alpha() const;

private:
    unsigned int m_argb;
};

class HSV {
public:
    static constexpr auto name = "HSV";

    HSV() = default;
    HSV(unsigned int h, unsigned int s, unsigned int v, unsigned int a = 0xFF);

    HSV lighter(double factor = 1.2) const;
    HSV complementary() const;
    HSV greyscale() const;

    unsigned int hue() const;
    unsigned int saturation() const;
    unsigned int value() const;
    unsigned int alpha() const;

private:
    unsigned int m_h, m_s, m_v, m_a;
};

typedef Color<RGB> RGBColor;
typedef Color<HSV> HSVColor;

template<typename From, typename To>
To ColorModelConverter(From model);
template<>
RGB ColorModelConverter<HSV, RGB>(HSV model);
template<>
HSV ColorModelConverter<RGB, HSV>(RGB model);
```

This seemed to be a good idea at first. However, multiple problems emerged, first of which is that the whole thing seems ugly and doomed.

In fact, I have two main problems, first is as follows : how to make models' methods return a color instead of a model (their own type) ?

```
Color<RGB> greyscale() const;
// ... instead of ...
RGB greyscale() const;
```

The other problem lies in the convertion between colors with different models :

```
template <typename U>
explicit Color(const Color<U>& c);
```

I originally planned to use model-converter functions in this constructor but I cannot set it up.

The idea behind this design is to be able to create new color models, with appropriate converters to and from existing ones, and use them with the Color class (that has a typedef for the model type and a general convertion constructor). *[edit]* In order to create a new color model, one should not need to (and simply should not) modify any of the existing class (models or the color class), but might want to write corresponding converters. *[edit]*

So my question is so : is my design possible to fix and, basically, a good design (after fixing) ? And if not, what are my possibilities in order to have about the same functionality as I specified ?

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but after all, I am not sure I understand your requirements. This whole thing looks like over-engineering. What are the real benefits compared to creating two independent classes `RgbColor` and `HsvColor`? Could you give a an example of client code which actually does not care which color model is being used?

Comment: `Color` IsA `RGB` (i.e. Color Model) or `Color` Has `RGB` (Color Model)? IOW, have you considered composition over inheritance?

Comment: @ChristianHackl There is no code that should not care about the model used. I am not using `Color` as a base, after all. The main benefit would be to have a converter constructor instead of functions, without modifying existing models if you add new ones (to add converters). The other "useful" thing in `Color` would be the `Model` typedef.

Comment: @rockoder I have indeed considered composition. As a matter of fact, I had a composition-oriented code before trying this approach. The problem is in the provided interface (which changes according to the model)

Comment: For the first problem: making `greyscale` virtual in base class (i.e. in `RGB`) should able you to have covariant return type in derive class (i.e. in `Color`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your comments:

> There is no code that should not care about the model used.

I think this is the gist of the problem.

If there is no model-independent `Color` client code, then neither templates nor object-orientation make sense.

You have basically created two completely independent classes which happen to have angle brackets in their names. Just create two completely independent non-template classes `RgbColor` and `HsvColor`. It should make your entire code much clearer.

> The main benefit would be to have a converter constructor instead of
>   functions, without modifying existing models if you add new ones (to
>   add converters).

I don't think this brings any real benefit, because you would still have to explicitly *implement* each and every conversion from model X to model Y. There is no real automation in any case.

A cleaner solution would be to write non-member non-friend conversion functions:

```
RgbColor ToRgb(HsvColor const &color);
HsvColor ToHsv(RgbColor const &color);
```

Non-member non-friend means that **none of the classes must be changed** if new models are added. It further means that all conversions are clearly visible in the client code, and accidental unwanted conversions are less likely to happen.

Another advantage is the support of one-directional conversions. For example, you may later need an RGB color class without alpha support. An instance of `RgbColorNoAlpha` should be convertible to an `RgbColor` but not vice versa. This requirement is trivially met by the code through the *absence* of `RgbColorNoAlpha ToRgbColorNoAlpha(RgbColor const &color)`.

Comment: This seems legit. So I reconsidered my design and am currently writing stand-alone classes. I will see what I do with color converters. I think I will keep the template in order to be able to convert using multiple steps (e.g. if there is HSL -> HSV and HSV -> RGB but no HSL -> RGB, the template will do HSL -> HSV -> RGB). I also reconsidered a Color base class, but I cannot really think of any use. Is there still a way to automatically provide conversion constructors ? If they are explicit, there will be no accidental conversion anyway.

Comment: @Nelxiost: I am not a computer graphics specialist, but don't you need pretty specialised algorithms to convert from one model to the other? How is the compiler supposed to automate such a task?

Comment: Of course you need specialized algorithms. I wanted a way to provide conversion constructors from conversion functions. I think having non-member functions to implement the algorithms is better anyway, but I would also like to automatically provide this syntax : `someHsvColor = HSV(someRgbColor);`

Comment: @Nelxiost: Thanks, I think I understand now, but still I question the benefits. Why is it this syntax better than `someHsvColor = ToHSV(someRgbColor);`

Comment: You are probably right, I suppose I am a bit manic. But in order to do what I talked about with the template converter function (for multiple steps conversions), I think I actually need a generic name like `ColorConverter<From, To>`. In that case, the (automatic) constructor syntax would be appreciable. Or is there another possibility ? How would you do ?

Comment: @Nelxiost: Again, I think the template is over-engineering. For multiple-step conversion, what's wrong with `Rgb ToRgb(Hsv const &hsv) { return ToRgb(ToHsl(hsv)); }`? This puts the logic exactly where it belongs to and is much easier to read and maintain. Now don't get me wrong, I'm actually a fan of C++ templates (and miss them a great deal every time I deal with generics in Java), but in this case they just don't feel like the right tool for the job...

Comment: This is because I don't know how many color models there might be, and I know I want to implement at least 6 or 7. So for every new color model you need to create 2 functions (for 2-way conversion) like the one you just wrote per existing color model. This is 14 functions for the 8th model, and so on. The other solution (yours) is to forbid any conversion by default except the ones you really need (if you want an alternate version of RGB, you only write the conversions to and from RGB, and that is all). I also feel like `return ToRgb(ToHsl(hsv));` is kind of ugly, but that is only an opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59068/discussion-between-nelxiost-and-christian-hackl).

Answer (score 1):

> The idea behind this design is to be able to create new color models, with appropriate converters to and from existing ones, and use them with the Color class (that has a typedef for the model type and a general convertion constructor).

This should be possible with template specialisation. You can implement one instance for every different color model combinition or implement one gerneric modell and have one private converter for this in every other color modell.

Comment: If I specialize the Color class instead of using inheritance, what can I use as template parameter ? I cannot use an enum because creating new models would be impossible without modifying the enum, and if I use a typename, I need another class that names the model but doesn't do anything else ? And also, I forgot to specify this (I edited), but creating new models should not involve modifying other models (or anything already written). How would you do it exactly ?

Comment: Christian Hackl answere seems better, with template specialisation and the same structure you need to modify old code for every new color modell

Answer (score 0):

consider this possibility:

```
struct HSV; //undefined
struct RGB; //undefined

template<class M> class color; //undefined

template<>
class color<RGB>
{
  //specific RGB implementations
};

template<>
class color<HSV>
{
  //specific HSV implementation
};
```

But as far your design actually concern, there is no common interface between RGC and HSV, so having them as *child* of a common *ancestor* makes very few sense.

Which function of type `fn(color<M>)` can you write if there are no common members in the various color implementation?